# How to easily use and access meta attributes in Eloquent - Laravel

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I have a 'contents' table like this :

```
id title description
```

I have another 'meta' table that stores extra fields for my contents :

```
id content_id field_name field_vaue
```

My question is How can I access MyModel->field_name as if it is in contents table
I know I can use hasMany relation but it's not satisfy my needs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Metable` extension from this package instead: **https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence**

If you want to do it yourself, then check its source - a bit too long to show it here!

Answer (score 0):

Your can use:

```
$new_table=DB::table('contents')
        ->join('meta', 'contents.id', '=', 'meta.content_id')
        ->get();
```

Now the $new_table will have the field_name and you can you it!

Hope it help!

Comment: Thanks but I want to use eloqent

Comment: What is your problem with hasMany?